# Regression Subset Algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, regression

I want to build a regression subset algorithm in R for a 'beta regression' model. 
There is a package `betareg` in R which fits beta regressions, and what I am interested in is the model that maximises the 'log likelihood'.

Basically, this works by picking the best k factor regression model, for k = 1,2,...,p where p is the number of variables you have.

For example, if i have x_1, x_2, x_3 as my variables, and y as my response. I want to have something that does:

step 1: Find best 1 factor model

```
mod1 <- betareg(y~x_1, data = test)
mod1.sum <- summary(mod1)

mod2 <- betareg(y~x_2, data = test)
mod2.sum <- summary(mod2)

mod3 <- betareg(y~x_3, data = test)
mod3.sum <- summary(mod3)
```

now that i have fit all the models, I want to compare the log likelihood of each:

```
 likelihoods <- c( mod1.sum$loglik, mod2.sum$loglik, mod3.sum$loglik)
which.max(likelihoods)
```

Step 2: find the best factor to add to the best 1 factor model, let's assume x_1 was the best in the previous step. Then in this step we compare the model with x_1 and x_2, to the model with x_1 and x_3 choosing the one with the biggest loglikelihood.

Step 3: taking the best two variables as a given, find the third variable contributing the largest increase to log likelihood.

Step 4: Return the best 1 factor model, best 2 factor model, ..., best p factor model, the factors included and their corresponding log likelihoods.

I am struggling to do this efficiently when p is large, say around 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my other answer that shows how to do *best-subset* selection for beta regression with `kofnGA`, I'm including an example how to do *forward* selection by hand.

We again start by loading the package and data:

```
library("betareg")
data("FoodExpenditure", package = "betareg")
```

I'm also setting up lists with the response plus all regressors (including 40 random ones. (Note that unlike in the other I'm keeping the intercept in `x` which is more convenient here.)

```
fe_data <- list(
  y = with(FoodExpenditure, food/income),
  x = model.matrix(~ income + persons, data = FoodExpenditure)
)
set.seed(123)
fe_data$x <- cbind(fe_data$x,
  matrix(rnorm(40 * nrow(fe_data$x)), ncol = 40))
colnames(fe_data$x)[4:43] <- paste0("x", 1:40)
```

Then we set up again a function for the negative log-likelihood (but do not need to include the intercept manually because it is still in `x`).

```
nll <- function(v, data) -betareg.fit(x = data$x[, v, drop = FALSE],
  y = data$y)$loglik
```

Then we store the index of all possible regressors `vall` and initialize our search with the intercept (`v <- 1`) and the corresponding negative log-likelihood (`n`).

```
vall <- 1:ncol(fe_data$x)
v <- 1
n <- nll(v, data = fe_data)
```

And then we iterate our forward search for 15 iterations (to avoid numerical instabilities on this small data set for higher numbers of variables). We always select that additional variable that decreases the negative log-likelihood most:

```
for(i in 1:15) {
  vi <- vall[-v]
  ni <- sapply(vi, function(vii) nll(v = c(v, vii), data = fe_data))
  v <- c(v, vi[which.min(ni)])
  n <- c(n, ni[which.min(ni)])
}
```

The sequence in which the variables are chosen is the following. Note that the real regressors are picked first, followed by the random noise regressors. (But try to `set.seed(1)` above which will include random regressors before the real ones...)

```
colnames(fe_data$x)[v]
##  [1] "(Intercept)" "income"      "persons"     "x28"         "x18"        
##  [6] "x29"         "x22"         "x11"         "x5"          "x8"         
## [11] "x38"         "x24"         "x13"         "x23"         "x36"        
## [16] "x16"
```

The corresponding decrease in the negative log-likelihood and associated BIC can be visualized as:

```
m <- seq_along(v)
plot(m, n, type = "b",
  xlab = "Number of regressors", ylab = "Log-likelihood")
plot(m, n + log(nrow(fe_data$x)) * (m + 1), type = "b",
  xlab = "Number of regressors", ylab = "BIC")
```

So this would indeed pick the model with the three real regressors as the best BIC model.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no dedicated efficient implementation of best-subset selection for beta regression (in R or otherwise). However, there are some generic implementations that provide approximate solutions to this, e.g., based on genetic algorithms such as the `kofnGA` package (on [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=kofnGA) and published in [JSS](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v068.c01)). See the example below. (To use *forward* search in stead of *best-subset* selection, see my other answer.)

Alternatively, you could use a (generalized) linear model that approximates what `betareg` does and use the subset selection for that. For example, you could logit-transform the response (i.e., `qlogis(y)`) and then run best-subset selection using a linear regression via `leaps` ([CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=leaps)) or `lmSubsets` ([R-Forge](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=517)). Or you could use a GLM with `family = quasibinomial` and use `glmulti` ([CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=glmulti), [JSS](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v034.i12)). And then you could use the best-subset result from that approximate model and employ it in a beta regression. Of course, this will not give you the *best* beta regression result but it might be a useful starting point for further analyses.

Therefore, back to the direct genetic algorithm for beta regression. To illustrate how this can be accomplished with `kofnGA` we first load packages and example data:

```
library("betareg")
library("kofnGA")
data("FoodExpenditure", package = "betareg")
```

Then, we construct a list with the response variable `y` and a regressor matrix `x`. Note that we omit the intercept here in order to force it into the model later (i.e., the intercept should not be subject to selection).

```
fe_data <- list(
  y = with(FoodExpenditure, food/income),
  x = model.matrix(~ income + persons, data = FoodExpenditure)[, -1]
)
```

In addition to the two regressors set up above we now add 40 random noise variables to the regressor matrix

```
fe_data$x <- cbind(fe_data$x,
  matrix(rnorm(40 * nrow(fe_data$x)), ncol = 40))
colnames(fe_data$x)[3:42] <- paste0("x", 1:40)
```

Now we can employ `kofnGA` to select the best model with 2 regressors out of the potential 42 regressors (plus the always-included intercept). As `kofnGA` minimizes an obejctive we use the negative log-likelihood provided by `betareg`. The workhorse function `betareg.fit` instead of `betareg` is used to avoid unnecessary formula parsing etc.

```
nll <- function(v, data) -betareg.fit(x = cbind(1, data$x[, v]),
  y = data$y)$loglik
```

Finally, we run the genetic algorithm just for 100 generations to save some computation time in this short example:

```
set.seed(1)
ga <- kofnGA(n = 42, k = 2, OF = nll, data = fe_data, ngen = 100)
```

The resulting output is

```
summary(ga)
## Genetic algorithm search, 100 generations
## Number of unique solutions in the final population: 1 
## 
## Objective function values:
##                      average   minimum
## Initial population -36.56597 -41.74583
## Final population   -45.33351 -45.33351
## 
## Best solution (found at generation 1):
## 1 2
```

Thus, in this very simple artificial setup the genetic algorithm indeed picks the first 2 regressors (from the real data) and not any of the irrelevant random 40 regressors we added. So we could now go ahead and refit a proper beta regression model with the regressors

```
colnames(fe_data$x)[ga$bestsol]
## [1] "income"  "persons"
```

etc. Note that the beta regression employed here simply uses a fixed precision parameter (with log link). If you want a variable dispersion then you would need to modify `nll` correspondingly.

Comment: thanks, i'd never used `kofnGA` before, so this is a best subset selection algorithm where the best 2 variable model is being chosen. I am wondering if there is a forward subset algorithm equivalent though? since this will be computationally intensive if i run it for all possible models of size k.. also im not quite sure what the `ngen = 100` parameter is doing? does this mean that the function only fits 100 models of size `k=2`? instead of the entire possible number of 40 choose 2  = 780?

Comment: `kofnGA` runs fewer models than all possible (actually 42 choose 2, here) but it does not do so by _simple_ random selection. It is a genetic algorithm that keeps a "population" of candidate models. In each generation some offspring are produced by random "mutation", "crossovers" etc. and only the fittest survive. This is repeated for 100 generations and only the fittest survivor is reported in the end. It's an optimization heuristic that is widely used in many fields and often works well when exhaustive search is computationally not feasible. See the JSS paper for `kofnGA` for more details.

Comment: Also, I've added a second answer on how to do forward search by hand (where all the usual caveats of forward search apply).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution without using betareg. The output is similar and for consideration for your issues.

Here's the dataset I'd used:

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- data.frame(y=runif(50), x_1=runif(50), x_2=runif(50), x_3=runif(50))
```

Using leaps library to create a list of all possible combinations:

```
library(leaps)
subs<-regsubsets(y~., data=dat, nbest=10, nvmax=100, really.big=T)
subs<-summary(subs)$which[,-1]
all.mods<-lapply(1:nrow(subs), function(x)paste("y", paste(names(which(subs[x,])), collapse="+"), sep="~"))

all.mods

[[1]]
[1] "y~x_2"

[[2]]
[1] "y~x_1"

[[3]]
[1] "y~x_3"

[[4]]
[1] "y~x_2+x_3"

[[5]]
[1] "y~x_1+x_2"

[[6]]
[1] "y~x_1+x_3"

[[7]]
[1] "y~x_1+x_2+x_3"
```

Running linear regression for all models:

```
all.lm<-lapply(all.mods, function(x)lm(as.formula(x), data=dat))
```

Check logLikihood for each model:

```
lapply(all.lm, logLik)

[[1]]
'log Lik.' -7.051835 (df=3)

[[2]]
'log Lik.' -9.288776 (df=3)

[[3]]
'log Lik.' -9.334048 (df=3)

[[4]]
'log Lik.' -6.904604 (df=4)

[[5]]
'log Lik.' -7.051584 (df=4)

[[6]]
'log Lik.' -9.215915 (df=4)

[[7]]
'log Lik.' -6.888849 (df=5)
```

Comment: isn't this a best subset algorithm? which will be very inefficient for p large? Also, would replacing lm by betareg give the result for beta regresson? not sure why you chose lm if it would be as simple to use betareg? Is this something to do with the leaps package?

Comment: I'm not using the leaps best subset function to determine the best subsets. Instead, I'm just using it to extract all possible combinations for predictors terms (hence the high nvmax and exhaustive/really.big method). It is the more effective way to write down all possible formulas if you have a large number of predictors (doesn't make sense if there's only 3 predictors).

Comment: As for lm, I'd used it cos I am too lazy to install/read up on betareg. I don't know what's the point of having so many different regression packages in the first place, when you could already extract beta coefficient from stats package.

Comment: but you fit a linear model to each possible combination of predictors ? doesn't that make it a best subset algorithm ?

Comment: Sorry, just read up on betareg. Seems like it's running logistic regression on the data instead of lm.

Comment: no, beta reg runs a Beta regression.. that is it assumes a beta distribution for the y variable. Using your solution wouldbe too slow in the case that p is large... I just wanted to know the best way to work out how to add the x variable with the biggest contribution of log likelihood

Comment: Anyway, you can still force betareg on all the models, by running `lapply(all.mods, function(x) betareg(as.formula(x), data=dat))`. It takes the first term as the starting term however.

Comment: the output for `betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data=GasolineYield)` is the same as `glm(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield, family=binomial(link="logit"))`

Comment: but binomial family assumes a binomial distribution, a beta reg assumes a beta distribution, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4679/55946

Comment: @dimebucker91 you are correct that beta regression is not equivalent to any of these (generalized) linear models. However, the results will often be similar, especially for `family = quasibinomial`. But there's no guarantee for that, of course. Still you might simply try out for your data if a best-subset selection for these yields something useful for beta regression as well. Alternatively, you could try to get an approximate best-subset selection by genetic algorithms for beta regression directly. I have set up a separate answer for this.